# ¿Cómo muestro el grupo de /etc/group si contiene al menos un usuario?

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, grep, cut

Quiero filtrar de tal manera que solo me salgan los grupos que tienen usuarios.

[image: filtrado-ssh]

En este caso, que "root" no saliese y solo aparecieran "adm", "disk", "dialot" y "fax" de los que se ven en la imagen.

Comment: por favor, da texto y no imágenes. También sería interesante que indicaras exactamente qué quieres y cómo. ¿Quieres coger todos los grupos y después mirar qué usuarios tienen asignados, para mostrar solamente los que no tienen ninguno?

Comment: Quiero filtar para que solo aparescan los grupos y los que tengan usuarios que por ejemplo root: no saliese y solo apareciera adm, disk, dialot y fax de los que se ven en la imagen

Comment: copia por favor el contenido del texto de la imagen y ponlo en la pregunta, para que podamos "jugar" con estos datos. En la imagen no se puede copiar nada.

Answer (score 3):

El fichero `/etc/group` tiene distintos campos separados por `:`. Lo que quieres en esencia es encontrar aquellas líneas que tengan valores en el campo 4 y, en tal caso, mostrar el campo 1.

Pues es muy rápido con awk:

```
awk -F: '$4!="" {print $1}' /etc/group
```

Esto define el separador como `:` usando `-F` y después comprueba que el campo cuarto no sea vacío. Si es el caso, imprime el primer campo.

Comment: muchas gracias, medianamente me sirvió, tendré en cuenta como formular la pregunta y sus correspondientes detalles, un saludo.

Comment: @javibetancort genial! Puedes leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y aceptar la respuesta si te ayudó.

Answer (score 2):

Una de mis propuestas es la opción con una expresión regular

```
sed -rn "s/^(.*):(.*:){2}.+/\1/p" /etc/group
```

Es decir, capturar lo que esté antes de ":", luego asegurarse de que se pasen otros dos ":" y después que existan caracteres después de esos últimos ":". Una vez hecho esto, se muestra lo capturado.

La otra propuesta es una reducción de lo que propuso @fedorqui

```
awk -F: '$4{print $1}' /etc/group
```

En esta simplemente no puse el `$4!=""` porque funciona con únicamente el `$4`, aunque desconozco la razón documentada del por qué.

Comment: la de sed me parece matar moscas a cañonazos : )

Comment: la de awk funciona con `$4`, bien visto. Esto es así porque las expresiones en awk son de la forma `condición {acción}`. Por tanto, `$4` funciona como condición directamente y es equivalente a decir "$4 existe" o "$4 no es nula" como dije yo, siendo tu opción más idiomática.

Comment: De hecho hice una pruebas y parece ser que la versión de `awk` es 3 veces más rápida que con la de `sed`.

Comment: supongo que en la versión de sed pesa bastante que utilices un regex _codicioso_ (greedy).

Answer (score 2):

Como los usuarios son la ultima columna, puedes simplemente buscar un `:` despues del cual hay caracteres que no son `:`, y solo caracteres que no son `:` hasta el final de la linea (`$`):

```
grep -E ':[^:]+$' /etc/group
```

Comment: Tengo un problema con lo que entiendo por lo que solicitó el que preguntó. El dijo "¿Cómo muestro el grupo?" pero luego dijo "quiero que sólo me salgan los grupos". En el primer caso, todas las respuestas las veo justas, pero en el segundo, sólo aplican para la de @fedorqui y la mia. Pero es ambiguo el asunto. Pero me gustó mucho tu aproximación así que anduve jugando un poco con la regex y obtuve esto `grep -Po '^\w*(?=.*:[^:]{1,}$)' /etc/group`